# Update InterfaceController with different data

Tags: watchkit, wkinterfacecontroller

Hi I am new to `WatchKit` development. I want to know that can I update a single interface controller with multiple data for button clicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have many different objects in your InterfaceController, such as labels, image views, etc.

**Updating `WKInterfaceLabel`s**

> You should call the setText() method on the corresponding label.

For example, you have a button and a label, and you want to print "Hello" on the label when the button is clicked. In this case, you should connect an action to the button in your interface (by control-dragging button to the code), and then add the following code in the method created:

*Swift*

```
label1.setText("Hello")
```

*Objective-C*

```
[label1 setText:@"Hello"];
```

**Updating `WKInterfaceImage`s**

> You should call setImage() or setImageNamed() methods on the corresponding image view.

First, the image should be located in the Asset Catalog of your WatchKit App Target, must be bundled or available as an `UIImage`. Then you could use these codes:

**Case #1: Available as file in bundle or Asset Catalog**

*Swift*

```
image1.setImageNamed("imageName")
```

*Objective-C*

```
[image1 setImageNamed:@"imageName"];
```

**Case #2: Available as an `UIImage`**

*Swift*

```
image1.setImage(image)
```

*Objective-C*

```
[image1 setImage:image];
```

If you want to have animated photos, try [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceImage_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014959-CH1-SW5).

**Conclusion**

1. To update `WKInterfaceLabel`s, you should call the setText() method on the corresponding label.
2. To update `WKInterfaceImage`s, you should call setImage() or setImageNamed() methods on the corresponding image view.

**Resources**

1. [`WKInterfaceImage` Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceImage_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceImage/setImageNamed:)
2. [`WKInterfaceLabel` Class Reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwji3OaK1KnMAhVIWywKHVYlCc8QFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FWatchKit%2FReference%2FWKInterfaceLabel_class%2F&usg=AFQjCNHu1Qr2fXtO3LgpqhLBNfhHUBieEQ)